# PowerShell: Members: Methods and Properties documentation in the ISE

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0, powershell-ise

Where could I get help documentation [examples] about methods and properties in the Powershell ISE. For example the `Join` method.

```
-join $a[3,4,5]; #trying to extract a part of a string
```

It is not even listed when I do `($a | gm)`.

Comment: Can you expand on what you want?

Comment: function Get-Diskinfo

{[cmdletbinding()]

param([string[]]$Computername='XEUTS001', [string[]]$drive='c:')

$a="-join $Computername[1..3]"

get-WmiObject win32_logicaldisk -Filter "DeviceID = '$drive'" -ComputerName $Computername -Credential (Get-Credential -Credential ayan-$a)| Select-Object @{n='Size';e={$_.size / 1gb -as [int]}}, @{n='free';e={$_.freespace / 1gb -as [int]}}, @{n='% free';e={$_.freespace / $_.size *100 -as [int]}} | Format-Table -AutoSize
}

Comment: I wrote this function to get some details about disks. However, I have to run them remotely and in a multi-domain environment. We have different usernames for computers in different OU's. I wanted the script to be able to take the username from the computername itself. 

The usernames are in this format---- "name"+ "first 3 letters of the computername" which is the OU name.

I am able to get the -Join method to work normally. However, it doesn't work if the variable is a parameter in a function.

Here the username shows up as "ayan--join xeuts001[1..3]"  when I want it to show up as "ayan-xeu"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are confusing between operators and cmdlets that are present in Powershell with methods and properties of (.NET) objects. `gm` or `Get-Member` will only show the latter.

You can learn about `-join` by doing `get-help about_join` or look here - http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847757.aspx

Take a look at `about_Operator` to learn about other available operators - http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847732.aspx

Answer (score 2):

That's because `-join` isn't a "method", it's an **operator**.

See <kbd>get-help about_operators</kbd> (look for `Split and Join Operators`) and <kbd>get-help about_join</kbd>.